# React - Children component not showing (beginner)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently following a tuto on a django react authentification app and I have encountered an issue. In the tutorial a children component is shown when selected on the nav bar, however, when I pass the {children} argument, all I get is a white page.

Here's my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from './hocs/Layout';

import Home from './containers/Home';
import Register from './containers/Register';
import Login from './containers/Login';
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard';


const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    </Layout>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

and the Layout componenent

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const layout = ({children}) => (
    <Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
    </Fragment>
);

export default layout;
```

When I get rid of the {children} everything is working as expected (expect for the children being displayed of course).

I use React 17.0.2 and the tutorial is more than 2 years old ...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't understand what any issue is with your rendering, the code appears correct, it renders without issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-banach-qj9m4?file=/src/App.js). Can you share your package.json file so we can confirm versions of npm modules used?

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router-dom version 6 (you can see the version in your package.json - dependencies) you have to use it like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './hocs/Layout';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import Register from './containers/Register';
import Login from './containers/Login';
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard';


const App = () => (
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
    <Layout>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>} />
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
      <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
    </Layout>
   </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, sadly it is still not working... I don't even have logs in the console to help me !

Comment: It seems OP is using RRDv5 since they make no mention of RRDv6 errors that would occur from incorrect use of `Route` components. BTW, you'd see these errors if using the code from your answer here. In RRDv6 all `Route` components **must** be wrapped in a `Routes` component, and you can't wrap a router within another router.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer, it worked by combining to two !

Comment: oh shure sry 
yes it have to wrapped in <Routes> not <Router> 
Regards

Comment: Then you may want to nest `Routes` *inside* `Layout` since only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of `Routes`.

Answer (score 0):

So if someone looks for the answer here's the right code :

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
    <Home  />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

I had to use both Routes and element

Comment: I see, so you *actually* managed to install `react-router-dom` v6, then yes, you'd need to apply these changes from what the tutorial likely used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all...
The component's name should start with Capital Letter
for example your layout component starts with lower case l not capital L
So React/Node might compile it to function or tag instead of component => Error

Second of all...
You if none of the answer mentioned above works try wrapping each components with Layout
for example

```
<Layout>
   <Home>
```

like this, then see how it works and try the methods in the previous answers